# Several controls bound (two way) on a same field in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have an issue with several controls bound on a same field. Let me explain with a simple example :

I have an instance of this class in my datacontext :

```
class X { string myVar; }
```

myVar is a composed variable, for instance contains things like "42;bar"
I have two TextBoxes bound on myVar in my Silverlight :

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding myVar, Mode=TwoWay, Converter=XConverter}" /><!-- 42 -->
<TextBox Text="{Binding myVar, Mode=TwoWay, Converter=YConverter}" /><!-- bar -->
```

XConverter knows how to convert myVar to 42.
YConverter knows how to convert myVar to bar.

But how can I ConvertBack ? For instance if I change 42 to 43, how can I recreate 43;bar ? Because in the converter, I don't have the previous value of myVar.

And I don't want to add properties to the class X (in this example, I have 2 controls bound on a field, but in reality, it's much more).

Thanks!

edit: And I don't want to add handlers such as TextChanged, I'd like a "Binding way" to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a multibinding http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/05/silverlight-multibinding-solution-for-silverlight-4/ for XConverter and YConverter (with the ConvertBack method filled in).

I would have each XConverter and YConverter bound to both textboxes. Then in XConverter replace only before the ; and YConverter replace after the ;

Answer (score 0):

I would probably utilize a decorator class for class X.

Internally, the decorator class would break the myVar into separate properties, each of which can be bound to the screen. Then you would have a ToX() method to get the X object back out of the decorator. That method would do the easy construction of the myVar property. Example is something like this:

```
public class X
{
  public string myVar { get; set; }
}

public class XDecorator
{ 
  public XDecorator(X x)
  {
    var pieces = x.Split(';');
    XPart = pieces[0];
    YPart = pieces[1];
  }


  public string XPart { get; set; }
  public string YPart { get; set; }

  public X ToX()
  {
    return new X { myVar = string.Format("{0};{1}", XPart, YPart) };
  }
}
```

Then, when you're setting this property on your ViewModel, you first wrap it in this decorator class. And when you go to save it, you call the ToX() method to get the X object out - the thing you really want. 
Hope that makes sense.